# I need to have my program add a .jpg to the GUI every time a wrong guess is made.

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, imageicon

this is the first time I have posted here, but this community has been a great help to me since I started programming. Basically, I'm working on a simple program that has a few different play modes for a hangman game. I have done some research on the this site and read through the API for some clues on how to implement the method that I'm stuck on. Everything in the program works great except for the part where I need to have an image added to the GUI every time a wrong guess is made. I have written a method called wrongGuess(); that reads a .jpg in and assigns it to a JLabel, but it will only add the picture to the GUI one time. I am extremely new to swing and AWT and find them a little frustrating. I am hoping that someone here can offer up a solution so I can deepen my knowledge base a little bit.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


public class GUI {

       private static String lettersFileName;
       private static String playerType;
       private static char guess;
       private static String guessString;
       private static HangmanPlayer aiPlayer;
       private static hangmanLogic hangmanGame;
       private final JPanel hangmanPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
       private JPanel graphicsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

       //Constructor
       GUI(String playerType, String lettersFileName, hangmanLogic hangmanGame){
           GUI.playerType = playerType;
           GUI.lettersFileName = lettersFileName;
           GUI.hangmanGame = hangmanGame;   
       }

   /**
     * Private listener subclass that allows a user to initiate a guess
     * The action is specific to the type of player (i.e. systematic AI,
     * random AI, or a human player)
     */
    public void drawGUI() {
        //Constructs AI player if applicable

        if (playerType.equals("s"))

        {

           aiPlayer = new SystematicPlayer(lettersFileName); 

        }

        else if (playerType.equals("r"))

        {

           aiPlayer = new RandomPlayer(lettersFileName); 

        }


      //Constructs a hangmanFrame
      HangmanFrame hangmanFrame = new HangmanFrame(500, 500);

      //Main section
      final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));

      //Title section
      final JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
      titlePanel.setBackground(new Color(40, 40, 40));
      final JLabel title = new JLabel("Let's Hang Out...");
      title.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 18));
      title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      titlePanel.add(title);

      //Left border section
      final JPanel leftBorderPanel = new JPanel();
      leftBorderPanel.setBackground(new Color(40, 40, 40));

      //Right border section
      final JPanel rightBorderPanel = new JPanel();
      rightBorderPanel.setBackground(new Color(40, 40, 40));

      //Hangman section (left sub-section)
      //final JPanel hangmanPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      hangmanPanel.setBackground(new Color(120, 120, 120));
      final JLabel hangmanTopCommentLabel = new JLabel("To Start Playing");
      hangmanTopCommentLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 16));
      hangmanTopCommentLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      hangmanTopCommentLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      hangmanPanel.add(hangmanTopCommentLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


      hangmanPanel.add(graphicsPanel);





      //Set images up for display   
      final JLabel image = new JLabel();
      hangmanPanel.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER);


      final JLabel hangmanBottomCommentLabel = new JLabel();
      hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 16));
      hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      hangmanPanel.add(hangmanBottomCommentLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      //Right sub-section
      final JPanel rightSubPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));

      //Revealed phrase section
      final JPanel phrasePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      phrasePanel.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
      phrasePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      final JLabel phraseTitleLabel = new JLabel("Revealed Phrase");
      phraseTitleLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 16));
      phraseTitleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      phrasePanel.add(phraseTitleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      final JLabel phraseLabel = new JLabel(hangmanGame.getRevealedKeyPhrase());
      phraseLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
      phraseLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      phraseLabel.setForeground(new Color(196, 0, 0));
      phrasePanel.add(phraseLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      //Already guessed letters section
      final JPanel alreadyGuessedPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      alreadyGuessedPanel.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
      alreadyGuessedPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      final JLabel alreadyGuessedTitleLabel = new JLabel(
            "Already Guessed Letters");
      alreadyGuessedTitleLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 16));
      alreadyGuessedTitleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      alreadyGuessedPanel.add(alreadyGuessedTitleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      final JTextArea alreadyGuessedLabel = new JTextArea("");
      alreadyGuessedLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 22));
      alreadyGuessedLabel.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
      alreadyGuessedLabel.setLineWrap(true);
      alreadyGuessedLabel.setEditable(false);
      alreadyGuessedPanel.add(alreadyGuessedLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      //Guesses remaining section
      final JPanel guessesRemaining = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      guessesRemaining.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
      guessesRemaining.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      final JLabel guessesRemainingTitleLabel = new JLabel("Guesses Remaining");
      guessesRemainingTitleLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 16));
      guessesRemainingTitleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      guessesRemaining.add(guessesRemainingTitleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      final JLabel guessesRemainingLabel = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
            hangmanGame.getnumberOfGuessesRemaining()));
      guessesRemainingLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 60));
      guessesRemainingLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      guessesRemaining.add(guessesRemainingLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      //Guess input section
      final JPanel guessInputPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());    
      guessInputPanel.setBackground(new Color(40, 40, 40));
      JButton guessButton = new JButton("Guess!");
      guessButton.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));
      guessButton.setBorderPainted(false);
      guessButton.setForeground(new Color(196, 0, 0));
      final JLabel playerTypeLabel = new JLabel();
      playerTypeLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));
      playerTypeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
      playerTypeLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      final JTextField guessField = new JTextField(10);
      guessInputPanel.add(playerTypeLabel);

      //Nests panels
      mainPanel.add(hangmanPanel);
      rightSubPanel.add(phrasePanel);
      rightSubPanel.add(alreadyGuessedPanel);
      rightSubPanel.add(guessesRemaining);
      mainPanel.add(rightSubPanel);

      //Modifies specific components to fit the player type
      if (playerType.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
      {
         playerTypeLabel.setText(("Systematic AI Player"));
         hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText(("Press Guess"));
         guessInputPanel.add(guessButton);
      }
      else if (playerType.equalsIgnoreCase("r"))
      {
         playerTypeLabel.setText(("Random AI Player"));
         hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText(("Press Guess"));
         guessInputPanel.add(guessButton);
      }
      else if (playerType.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
      {
         playerTypeLabel.setText(("Human Player"));
         hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText(("Enter A Guess"));
         guessInputPanel.add(guessField);
         guessInputPanel.add(guessButton);

         /**
          * Private listener subclass that selects all text
          * in the guessField when it receives a mouse click
          *
          */
         class GuessFieldMouseListener implements MouseListener
         {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
            { 
               //Selects all text
               guessField.requestFocus();
               guessField.selectAll();

            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
            {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event)
            {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event)
            {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
            {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            }
         }

         //Adds guessFieldListener to guessField
         MouseListener guessFieldListener = new GuessFieldMouseListener();
         guessField.addMouseListener(guessFieldListener);
      }

      /**
       * Private listener subclass that allows a user to initiate a guess
       * The action is specific to the type of player (i.e. systematic AI,
       * random AI, or a human player)
       */
      class GuessActionListener implements ActionListener
      {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
         {  
            /* 
             * Accepts a guess from a given player type and assigns guessString
             * (s - AI systematic, r - AI random, or h - human)
             * and determines if the guess is part of the key phrase
             */
               if (playerType.equals("s"))
               {
                  guess = aiPlayer.makeGuess();  

                  guessString = Character.toString(guess).toUpperCase();
               }
               else if (playerType.equals("r"))
               {
                  guess = aiPlayer.makeGuess(); 

                  guessString = Character.toString(guess).toUpperCase();
               }
               else if (playerType.equals("h"))
               {
                  guess = guessField.getText().charAt(0);

                  guessString = Character.toString(guess).toUpperCase();
               }
               //Determines if the game is already over
               if (!hangmanGame.isGameOver())
               {
                  try
                  {  
                     //Determines if the guess is part of the key phrase
                     if (hangmanGame.guessCharacter(guess))
                     {  
                        //Determines if the current guess ended the game
                        if (hangmanGame.isGameOver())
                        {
                           if (hangmanGame.getKeyPhrase().equals(
                                 hangmanGame.getRevealedKeyPhrase()))
                           {
                              //Updates comment labels
                              hangmanTopCommentLabel.setText("You Win!!!");
                              hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText("Game Over!");
                           }
                           else
                           {
                              //Updates comment labels
                              hangmanTopCommentLabel.setText("You Lose!!!");
                              hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText("Game Over!");
                           }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           //Updates comment labels
                           hangmanTopCommentLabel.setText("Current Guess: " +
                                 guessString);
                           hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText("CORRECT!");  

                           //image.setIcon( new ImageIcon("madBro.jpg") );



                        }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        if (hangmanGame.isGameOver())
                        {
                           //Updates comment labels
                           if (hangmanGame.getKeyPhrase().equals(
                                 hangmanGame.getRevealedKeyPhrase()))
                           {
                              hangmanTopCommentLabel.setText("You Win!!!");
                              hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText("Game Over!");
                           }
                           else
                           {
                              hangmanTopCommentLabel.setText("You Lose!!!");
                              hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText("Game Over!");
                           }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           //Updates comment labels
                           hangmanTopCommentLabel.setText("Current Guess: " +
                                 guessString);
                           hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText("WRONG!");




                           //image.setIcon( new ImageIcon("realMad.jpg") );
                           wrongGuess();    


                        }
                     }

                     //Updates guessesReaminingLabel and phraseLabel
                     guessesRemainingLabel.setText(
                           Integer.toString(
                                 hangmanGame
                                 .getnumberOfGuessesRemaining()));
                     phraseLabel.setText(
                           hangmanGame.getRevealedKeyPhrase());

                     /* 
                      * Allows the alreadyGuessedLabel to be updated
                      * with a comma delimited list of the already
                      * guessed characters
                      */
                     if (alreadyGuessedLabel.getText().equals(""))
                     {
                        alreadyGuessedLabel.setText(
                              alreadyGuessedLabel.getText() + " " +
                                    guessString);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        alreadyGuessedLabel.setText(
                              alreadyGuessedLabel.getText() +
                              ", " + guessString);
                     }
                  }
                  catch (InvalidInputException e)
                  {
                     //Updates comment labels
                     hangmanTopCommentLabel.setText("Current Guess: " +
                           guessString);
                     hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText("Invalid Input!");

                  }
                  catch (AlreadyGuessedException e){
                     //Updates comment labels
                     hangmanTopCommentLabel.setText("Current Guess: " +
                           guessString);
                     hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText("Already Guessed!");
                  }
               }
               else
               {
                  //Updates comment labels
                  hangmanTopCommentLabel.setText("The Game is Over!");
                  hangmanBottomCommentLabel.setText("Give It Up!");
               }
         }
      }

      //Adds guessListener to guessButton
      ActionListener guessListener = new GuessActionListener();
      guessButton.addActionListener(guessListener);

      //Adds components to the frame
      hangmanFrame.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      hangmanFrame.add(leftBorderPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
      hangmanFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      hangmanFrame.add(rightBorderPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
      hangmanFrame.add(guessInputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      //Makes the hangman GUI visible
      hangmanFrame.setVisible(true);
   }

    /**
     * Adds new graphic representation for each wrong guess made
     */
    private void wrongGuess()
    {
        ImageIcon broMad = createImageIcon("madBro.jpg");
        JLabel wrong = new JLabel(broMad);
        graphicsPanel.add(wrong);
    }
    /**
     * Method for creating an image icon, found in Oracle.com's knowledge base
     * @param path location of desired image file
     * @return Icon, or null if path not found
     */
    private ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) 
    {
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some advice and questions:

- First and foremost, you will want to get rid of all static modifiers on your variables. Your Swing GUI should use well-behaved object oriented code, and there's little place for static variables with a few exceptions.
- You appear to be considering calling `setIcon(...)` on your image JLabel but have it commented out. Why? This is the correct method to use when you desire to swap images desplayed by the JLabel.
- When trying to add a new bit of complex functionality to a program, I find that it's usually best to try to get it working in isolation first before trying to add it to the larger more complex program. Consider creating a *much* simpler GUI, one that reads in a couple of Images into ImageIcons, and see if you can swap images on JButton push in this simpler program. If you get it to work, then it should be fairly straightforward bringing this functionality into the greater program.
- Note that if your images aren't that large, you could read them all into the program at start up and put them in ImageIcons that you can swap when desired.

Comment: First, thank you for the pointer on the static variable. I am new the java and I know I have picked up some bad habits. static variables being one of them. I was experimenting with setIcon at the time, but I don't think it is capable of what i need to do. Every time a player guesses wrong I need to add the same image to the GUI. So, if there are two bad guesses I need two images to show up on the GUI. Three bad guesses = three images, so on and so forth. Your other pointers on experimenting with new features are probably spot on as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at a PC at the moment so I can't run the code, but this

```
  hangmanPanel.add(graphicsPanel);

  //Set images up for display   
  final JLabel image = new JLabel();
  hangmanPanel.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Pops it at me

Basically, you add the `graphicsPanel` to the `hangmanPanel`, by default, in the `CENTER` position, then override it with the `image` label, effectively removing the `graphicsPanel`

Comment: What I have discovered is that basically the images are getting added as I want them to. The problem is that they're being stacked on top of each other. So the only way to see them is to changes the size of the GUI window as they're being added so that they initialize at different coordinates. The challenge at this point is controlling the manner in which the images are added so they are displayed properly. i.e not stacked on top of each other. 
Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

> ..a hangman game.

For Hangman, you would typically draw all the graphic elements to one single image which you might then display in a (single) label.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling repaint() on whole JFrame after all changes are made.

Comment: Hey just some feedback to everyone that tried to help me. I was able to solve this by added the picture to a panel with a GridLayout. I want to thank everyone for their insight and time.
Peace.